# MongoDB error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to run this command:

```
mongodump  --port 27017  -d local -c oplog.rs -q '{ts:{$gt: Timestamp(1578475955, 1)}}' -o /data/dump/inc/
```

but for some reason im getting this error:

```
Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input
```

what's the issue?

Comment: Most likely your json not formatted correctly. Just try to validate using an online validator (probably your keys not quoted).

Comment: On what JSON it's referring? the oplog right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ts:{$gt: Timestamp(1578475955, 1)}}` is JavaScript, not extended JSON. See https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/extended-json.rst for the extended JSON description.

The correct formulation is `{"ts":{"$gt": {"$timestamp":{"t":1578475955, "i":1}}}}`.